# How to set a macro to delete a row/multiple rows from a changing number of sheets

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook that has an increasing number of sheets (1 per month, keeps track of absence scores on a monthly basis). When a member of staff leaves I need to be able to delete them from the entire workbook. I presently have it set to delete the past 6 months, as this is all the score is calculated on, but I need it to remove that member of staff entirely. This is what I am using (with the sheets.count increasing in number to delete 6 months) at present.

```
Sheets(Sheets.Count - 2).Select
Last = Cells(Rows.Count, "J").End(xlUp).Row
For i = Last To 1 Step -1
    If (Cells(i, "J").Value) = "y" Then
        Cells(i, "A").EntireRow.Delete
    End If
Next i
```

Due to the increasing number of sheets I don't know how to set it to delete across the whole thing?  Any help would be appreciated!

Also, it needs to not delete from sheet 2, nor the last two sheets (these hold other info).

I am not experienced in this area and all my vba work is poorly self taught, with little knowledge, or using answers found on here and altered to my needs.

Comment: To be clear, it does need to be able to delete from `Sheet1` but not `Sheet2` or the last two sheets?

Comment: Correct. It needs to delete on sheet 1, skip sheet 2, delete from however many sheets there are, and then not delete from the last 2 sheets.

Comment: Thanks. I think that's what my code (below) achieves and from your comment it appears to have worked for you.

Comment: At least it had worked? I am now getting a run-time error '13': Type Mismatch. 
Chucks up this line as the issue:
If .cells(i, "J") = "y" Then

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Sub RemoveStaffMember()
    Dim sht As Worksheet, Last As Long, i As Long

    For Each sht In ThisWorkbook.Sheets        
        If sht.Index <> 2 And sht.Index < (ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count - 1) Then
            With sht
                Last = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "J").End(xlUp).Row

                For i = Last To 1 Step -1
                    If .Cells(i, "J") = "y" Then
                        .Cells(i, "A").EntireRow.Delete
                    End If
                Next i

            End With
        End If            
    Next sht
End Sub
```